# Clipboard management with 'Paste all Functionality' for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard

I've just frustratingly spend a couple of hours looking for some way to paste multiple items recently copied in one go. I.e copy a line, copy another line, copy a link, then 'PASTE ALL'

I've tried

- pastie
- glipper
- clipit
- diodon
- xlip
- xsel

… and nothing will do it.

This seems like a really simple thing. How can I achieve that, maybe through a Python script or something?

I'm using 32bit Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can be done easily by a shell script using of the tools above.

Comment: @artistoex how would I do that? With xclip?

Comment: Straight forward. Poll the clipboard. Log every new state in a temporary file and upon some kind of signal (e.g. keystroke) write the accumulated lines back to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

[Diodon](https://launchpad.net/diodon) has plugins by [RedHatter](https://github.com/RedHatter/diodon-plugins), one of which is `paste-all`, but compiling it fails on my machine. Maybe you have more luck, and are able to tell me how to get them compiled. I want this too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this today with clipit:

```
strings ~/.local/share/clipit/history
```

I tried to make it a keyboard shortcut from the keyboard manager with no luck so I just

Comment: … "so you just" what?